# Weak convergence $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f_n^2 \rightharpoonup g$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ implies $f^2\leq g$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

> $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f_n^2 \rightharpoonup g$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then $f^2\leq g$ a.e.

Could you guys help me check the proof please, thanks!

**Proof:** to show $f^2 \leq g$ a.e. it suffices to show that for any measurable set $A$ with $\mu(A) >0$ we have
$$\int_A f^2 \leq \int_A g. $$
$$\bigg(\int_A f^2 \bigg)^2 = \bigg(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_A f_n f \bigg)^2 \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \bigg(\int_A f_n^2 \bigg)\bigg(\int_A f^2 \bigg) = \bigg(\int_A g \bigg)\bigg(\int_A f^2 \bigg),$$
and because $\int_A f^2 \geq 0$, we have the desired result.

Comment: This looks fine.

Comment: @Etienne Thank you very much!

Comment: convergence in $L^p$ implies there is a subsequence which converges a.e., so $f^2 = g$ a.e.

Comment: @LiuGang: You only have weak convergence here! In this case, you don't necessarily have convergence a.e. for a subsequence.

Comment: @PhoemueX It's said as convergence in $L^2$ and $L^1$, isn't it?

Comment: @LiuGang I used the notation $\rightharpoonup$ for weak convergence. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Maybe some steps could be justified: for example, write:
"Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have for each integer $n$, 
$$\tag{*}\left(\int_A f_nf\right)^2\leqslant \left(\int_Af_n^2\right)\left(\int_Af^2\right).$$
On one hand, since $f_n\to f$ weakly in $L^2$ and $\chi_Af\in L^2$, the LHS of (*) converges to $\left(\int_A f^2\right)^2$. On the other hand, since $\chi_A\in L^\infty$, we get $\lim_n\int_Af_n^2=\int_Ag$, hence $\int_Af^2\leqslant \int_Ag$."